# Up vs. down with verbs

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs, antonyms

Often I read "up" and "down" with some verbs. For example: "write down", "take down", "wake up", "open up". Some of them (maybe all of them?) can be used in both: "break up" and "break down".

So, my questions are:

- What does "up" and "down" change in meaning of the verb?
- Can I use "up" and "down" with all verbs or just with some of them?
- Should I always append (for example) "up" to "wake" when I say to somebody that he must wake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called as [adverbial particles](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/adverbial-particle). They just emphasize the verbs and removing them *may not* change the meaning of the sentence. Consider this...

> The teachers *give <del>away</del>* the awards to the brilliant students in their classes

But that's not the case always. In some sentences, these particles play crucial role in making the sentence understandable.

> *Switch off the light* - You cannot remove the *adverbial particle* here.

Beware, you cannot simply put these particles to any verb. [Write up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/write-up) and [write down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/write+down) have different meanings.

Good read [here](http://www.englishgrammar.org/adverb-particles-prepositions/) and [here](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/adverb-particles/).